# what does string.split(/(,\n\s+)/) do

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw a code snippet like this

```
// o is a string
var o = JSON.stringify({
"name": "my title",
"version": "0.0.2",
"description": "my desc",
"main": "index.js"}, null, 2)

o.split(/(,\n\s+)/)
.map(function (e, i) {
  return i%2 ? '\n'+e.substring(4)+' ,' : e
})
.join('');
```

What is `/(,\n\s+)/` doing in the split function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/(,\n\s+)/` is a regexp literal that matches a comma, followed by a newline, followed by at least one space.

You can read more about regular expressions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it tries to split an indented JSON snippet to get the key-value pairs separated. This approach is very brittle because it assumes an exact format for the snippet. It does not work if there is e.g. a space after a comma before the newline. There are many cases where this does not work. So unless this is used in an environment where this particular JSON formatting is guarateed the code could be considered weak.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
**Capturing parentheses** example `string.split([separator][, limit])`

If separator contains capturing parentheses, matched results are returned in the array.

```
var myString = "Hello 1 word. Sentence number 2.";
var splits = myString.split(/(\d)/);

console.log(splits);
```